# is there a way to print a float input into a specified number of characters?

Tags: c++, string, input, printing

printf("%40s", "%.2f", AMOUNT);
im trying to print the computed price lets say 100 as the value of the chicken but it only prints "%.2f"

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. That way, we can see exactly what you are doing. This is currently unclear, because you are not showing us the definition of `AMOUNT`.

Comment: You have tagged the question with the `c++` tag. Was this intentional? Is your question about C or C++? I am asking because `printf` is mainly used in C and only seldomly in C++.

Answer (score 1):

`printf("%.2f", AMOUNT);` would be enough. Make sure `AMOUNT` is `double` though.
Or, if you use `cout`, you will have to `#include <iomanip>` and do the following code:

```cpp
cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << AMOUNT;
```